# How to pass the name of a dictionary

Tags: python

In the following code block i want to transmit just the name of a dictionary (result_dict) but not the content.

```
def define_var(dictionary, entry, counter):
  for i in range(counter):
    print "reason%d = %s['%s_%d']" % (i + 1, dictionary, entry, counter)
```

when i call the function like:

```
define_var(result_dict, 'start', 3)
```

it prints:

> reason1 = {'start_2': 'test2', 'start_3': 'test3', 'start_1': 'test1'}['start_1']

but i want to print it like that:

> reason1 = result_dict[start_1]
>
> reason2 = result_dict[start_2]

and so on

Comment: The idea of the "name" of the dictionary makes no sense for Python.

Comment: From your code there is no way for the function to magically know that you think your dictionary is called `result_dict`, unless you pass in the string `"result_dict"`.

Comment: when i call the function i write result_dict as first parameter. but it prints me the content of result_dict instead of 'result_dict'

Comment: do you have more than one dict defined?

Comment: yea. got many dicts.

Comment: The "name" of a variable (e.g. dictionary) is not an intricate part of the variable. Instead, it is a tag, floating in the namescope of the code that points to the variable. When you write ``define_var(result_dict)`` the function receives a pointer to the variable. In this sense, the "name" of the dictionary has no meaning to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the object in globals:

```
def define_var(dictionary, entry, counter):
    d_name = next(k for k, v in globals().items() if v  is  dictionary)
    for i in range(counter):
        print("reason%d = %s['%s_%d']" % (i + 1, d_name, entry, counter))

print(define_var(result_dict, 'start', 3))


reason1 = result_dict['start_3']
reason2 = result_dict['start_3']
reason3 = result_dict['start_3']
```

If you `print(id(result_dict))`  and `print(id(dictionary))` in the function when you pass in `result_dict`
    you will see they both are the same object with the same id's so we just use `is` to get the name from the `global` dict.

If you want to assign the result to a reason variable you can return it, something like:

```
def define_var(dictionary, entry, counter):
    d_name = next(k for k, v in globals().items() if v is dictionary)
    return "%s['%s_%d']" % (d_name, entry, counter)

reason  = define_var(result_dict,2,3)
print(reason)
```

Or use a dict:

```
def define_var(dictionary, entry, counter):
    d_name = next(k for k, v in globals().items() if v  is  dictionary)
    reasons = {}
    for i in range(counter):
        reasons["reason{}".format(i)] = "{}[{}]".format(d_name, entry)
    return reasons
```

Comment: thanks man! i'm still new to python. don't know how it works, but it works and i'll find out! is there any way i can give you a honor or something similar?

Comment: @AlexHeld, it just checks identity using `is` which checks if two objects are in fact the same object to  find the name of the `dictionary` passed from  the `globals()` dict.

Comment: damn. using above but i got problems with assigning the variable using `eval("reason%d = %s['%s_%d']" % (i + 1, d_name, entry, counter"`. i know eval is a security risk but i won't publish  the final program so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @AlexHeld "honor or something similar" - accept the answer (and upvote it)

Comment: @AlexHeld, why do you need eval?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, i need it for assign the variable. or is there a better and safer way  to do it?

Comment: @AlexHeld, use a dict